# Append to the beginning of an array (before the first item), not to the end in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to append a value to an array, but as the first item not the last one.

Comment: Insert it at index zero.

Answer (score 0):

As Magnas commented..

```
 var array = [1,2,3]
 array.insert(0, at: 0)
 print(array)
 // 0,1,2,3
```